# Increased in number commands in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

An increase in the number of visitors generates an increase in the number of commands issued on MongoDB. This makes the database slow and whole system unusable. Mongostat looks like so during those peak times:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults locked % idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
 0    266      0      0       3      19       0  58.7g   119g    13g      2        0          0       0|0     0|0    47k     1m   167   14:24:30
 0    308      4      0       0       8       0  58.7g   119g    13g      5      0.7          0       0|0     0|0    54k   880k   167   14:24:31
 0    177      3      0       0      34       0  58.7g   119g    13g      0      0.5          0       0|0     0|0    49k   559k   173   14:24:32
 0     73      2      0       0       8       0  58.7g   119g    13g      0      0.3          0       0|0     0|0    21k   288k   174   14:24:33
 0    201      5      0       0      27       0  58.7g   119g    13g      2      0.5          0       0|0     1|0    51k   639k   167   14:24:34
 0    232      4      0       0       9       0  58.7g   119g    13g      1      0.3          0       0|0     0|0    44k   456k   167   14:24:35
 0    102      2      0       0     109       0  58.7g   119g  13.1g      0      0.3          0       0|0     0|0    33k   269k   193   14:24:36
 0    265      3      0       0     103       0  58.7g   119g  13.1g      0      0.5          0       0|0     0|0    76k   714k   178   14:24:37
 1    277      4      0       0      16       0  58.7g   119g  13.1g      2      0.5          0       0|0     0|0    71k   501k   180   14:24:38
 0    237      3      0       0      92       0  58.7g   119g  13.1g      0      0.4          0       0|0     0|0    54k   670k   201   14:24:39
```

The problem is: I can't find out the source of those commands in my code. I've tried turning on full profiling (logging ALL the queries), but couldn't find any of those commands. I see some, but only few per second, usual stuff. Sometimes there are 100-200 commands per second for few minutes, but all I see in logs and profiler is authentication commands (this is php scripts reconnecting back after they have died out with time out).

How can I debug this issue and find the source of too many commands?

Comment: How many httpd processes are you running?
The PHP Driver will issue internal ping and isMaster commands to the server every few seconds, for each alive process.
If you have 500 very active httpd processess, you'll get 500 pings every 5seconds, and 500 ismaster commands every 15 seconds.
These are internal to the driver and are needed to make sure the driver knows the state of the replicaset, in case there is a failover going on or a new secondary added, and to track the performance of the secondaries for your reads...

Answer (score 0):

Commands can be a [number of things](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) including getLastError(), count(), sharding or replication related commands. Most commands such as count shouldn't really effect performance. Others like group or distinct possibly will. But they should show up in [profiler log](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) which you already mentioned. 
The number of queries in your mongostat output isn't very impressive tbh. In case each query is indexed MongoDB should not have problems at all dealing with them. Are you sure the problem is really the database instead of your application code or other running processes?

Comment: Also I believe a protocol write concern will issue a getLastError command.

Comment: Did you mean "In case each query is indexed MongoDB should NOT have problems at all dealing with them"?